# how to pass ansible group_vars array to jinja template

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to template a python script using ansible jinja2. When I pass the iterated item to the template to further generate a python dictionary is not working.

Thanks in advance for any help!.

```
[group_vars]
backups:
- sap

sap:
- db_host: sadf
- db_name: xyz
- db_user: xzzx
- db_pass: alskdf
```

ansible template looks like:

```
- name: transfer backup script file
  template:
    src: backup.py.j2
    dest: "{{ item }}_backup.py"
    mode: 0755
  with_items:
    - "{{ backups }}"
```

jinja python template looks like:

```
dbs = {
  {% for mongo_d in item %}

    "{{ mongo_d.db_name }}" :
    {
    "db_host": "{{ mongo_d.db_host }}",
    "db_user": "{{ mongo_d.db_user }}",
    "db_password": "{{ mongo_d.db_password }}",
 ]},

 {% endfor %}
```

failing with error:

```
item: sap
  msg: 'AnsibleUndefinedVariable: ''unicode object'' has no attribute ''db_name'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is cumbersome, use a dictionary instead of a list with single key-value pairs:

```
backups:
  - sap

sap:
  db_host: sadf
  db_name: xyz
  db_user: xzzx
  db_password: alskdf
```

You don't need to iterate inside the template.

The task:

```
- name: transfer backup script file
  template:
    src: backup.py.j2
    dest: "{{ item }}_backup.py"
    mode: 0755
  with_items:
    - "{{ backups }}"
  vars:
    mongo_d: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
```

The template:

```
dbs = {
    "{{ mongo_d.db_name }}" :
    {
    "db_host": "{{ mongo_d.db_host }}",
    "db_user": "{{ mongo_d.db_user }}",
    "db_password": "{{ mongo_d.db_password }}",
 ]},
```

<sup>I corrected `db_password` typo, but for inconsistencies in the template, I left them as posted in the question.</sup>

Comment: awesome great @techraf.